# Топ чисел в python

Tags: python

есть список чисел, у примеру: 1307, 1201, 1567, и т.д. Как в питон сдлеать чтобы они попали в список по убыванию? Чтоб получился такой список: 1567, 1307, 1201?

Comment: `_list.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: Только это - по убыванию.

Comment: По убыванию, извините)

Comment: Спасибо  большое

Answer (score 2):

```
listB = [24, 13, -15, -36, 8, 22, 48, 25, 46, -9]
listB.sort(reverse=True)
print(listB)
```

И ставишь свои числа)

Comment: Спасибо  большое

Comment: Без проблем))))

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: your_list = [1567, 1307, 1201]                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [4]: sorted(your_list)                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[4]: [1201, 1307, 1567]

In [5]: your_list                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[5]: [1567, 1307, 1201]
```

Можно использовать `sorted`, но нужно понимать, что он не обновляет список, поэтому `sorted(your_list)` нужно присвоить чему-то.

```
In [7]: update_list                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[7]: [1201, 1307, 1567]
```

так как вам нужен список с большего числа к меньшему, используем `reverse`

```
In [11]: sorted(your_list, reverse=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[11]: [1567, 1307, 1201]
```

так же это можно сделать с помощью функции списка `sort`

```
In [13]: your_list                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[13]: [1307, 1201, 1567]

In [14]: your_list.sort(reverse=True)                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [15]: your_list                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[15]: [1567, 1307, 1201]
```

[Объяснение в англоязычной документации можно посмотреть здесь](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html#sorting-basics)

Answer (score 0):

вообще "Топ чисел" наверное предполагает как результат - n максимальных элементов

```
s = [5, 7, 9, 1, 3]
n = 3
heapq.nlargest(n, s)  # [9, 7, 5]
```